# Send data between php pages

Tags: php

I have a page called 'edit members': a list of all members with options, such as edit or delete. When I press edit or delete, it opens a second tab where you can alter data [...]. When finished, it just closes the tab. What I want: close the tab (already working) and then reload the edit page. Any good ideas?

Comment: Use websockets to connect and send data between the pages.

Comment: you can use Ajax to save and reload data?

Answer (score 0):

Your going to have to look at JavaScript and AJAX/WebSockets because what you want to do happens on the clients machine and as a server side language PHP cant do it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without ajax.

You can call javacript on the origin tab using [Window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener).

For example, in tab A you open tab B to edit an entity. When saving, in tab B you call:

```
window.opener.location.reload(); // Reloads tab A
window.top.close(); // Closes tab B
```

Comment: could you please elaborate your warning?

Comment: @Jan Looked into it more and it appears that I was wrong in my warning - I removed it. You dont have to worry about external URL's because it would fail the same-origin security policy that pretty much all browsers require.